# getelementbyid issue with radio button

Tags: html, radio-button, alert

I'm trying to make an alert with the value of the selected radio button, but I allways get the first of them, regardless the one I choose...(Acompanhado);

html:

```
          <form/>

          <input type="radio" class="simple_form" name="grupo_1" value="Acompanhado" id="saida"/>
          <span class="texto">Acompanhado</span>
          <input type="radio" class="simple_form" name="grupo_1" value="Individual" id="saida"/>
          <span class="texto">Individual</span>
          </form>
```

js:

```
           function save() {
       var saida_js = document.getElementById('saida').value;
       alert("Tipo de saida: " + saida_js);
           }
```

Any idea ?

---

@Quentin: I have alot of alerts, cause Im trying to get all data from a form. I used your code, and I get no alert at all.

```
function save() {
    var morada_js = document.getElementById('morada').value;
    var data_js = document.getElementById('data').value;
    var hora_js = document.getElementById('hora').value;

    var radio_saida = document.getElementsByName('name_saida');

    var notas_js = document.getElementById('notas').value;
        var condicoes_atm_js = document.getElementById('condicoes_atm').value;


    alert("Morada: " + morada_js);
    alert("Data: " + data_js);
    alert("Hora: " + hora_js);

        function get_checked_radio(radio_saida) {
        for (var i = 0; i < radio_saida.length; i++) {
            var current = radio_saida[i];
            if (current.checked) {
                return current;
                }
            }
        }

    alert(get_checked_radio(radio_saida).value);
    alert("Notas: " + notas_js);

}
```

Comment: ID tags must be unique. You can have class names on each element that are the same but not IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `id` must be unique in a document.

To find the value of a selected radio button in a group, get the group by its name…

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('radio_name'); // or
var radios = document.forms.formId.elements.radio_name;
```

Then loop over them until you find the one with the true `checked` property.

```
function get_checked_radio(radios) {
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        var current = radios[i];
        if (current.checked) {
            return current;
        }
    }
}

alert(get_checked_radio(radios).value);
```

Comment: I understood, but now I cant make the loop. I'm trying with a for loop, but it is missing something...

Comment: @NelsonSilva — I have absolutely no idea why the code you haven't shown me isn't working.

Comment: I have alot of alerts, cause Im trying to get all data from a form. I used your code, and I get no alert at all.

Comment: Your HTML says `name="grupo_1"` but your JS says `getElementsByName('name_saida')`. You have to get the inputs by the names they have. `group_1 != name_saida`

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense because you've got two `input` tags with the same id `saida`